# Custom View over XML Layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I have made a custom View DrawView.java, where i drew a simple line. I want this custom view overlay my activity_main.xml for my MainActivity.java. For testing purposes, there is a simple Button in the XML file. The drawn line should draw itself over the Button. At the moment, the drawn line lies under the button, respectively under the XML View.

How can i achieve this, and in a perfect world still keep the button clickable? ;)

DrawView.java

```
public class DrawView extends LinearLayout {
Paint paint = new Paint();

private int endX;
private int endY;
private int startX;
private int startY;

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, this, true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);

}

public void setCoordinates(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    this.endX = endX;
    this.endY = endY;
    this.startX = startX;
    this.startY = startY;
}}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener{

DrawView drawView;

private int number;
private Handler handler;
private boolean Running = true;
private int endX = 500;
private int endY = 500;
private int startX = 50;
private int startY = 50;
private int frames = 25;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (Running) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int coordX = ((((endX - startX) / frames) * number))
                                + startX;
                        int coordY = ((((endY - startY) / frames) * number))
                                + startY;
                        number += 1;
                        drawView.setCoordinates(startX, startY, coordX,
                                coordY);
                        setContentView(drawView);
                        if ((coordX - endX) == 0 && coordY - endY ==0) {
                            Running = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="de.trialar.linedrawer.MainActivity"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Update:

Hi Martin, i tried your solution and it kind of works for me. I used your method with a Imageview instead. And my line is drawn, when i click a button. Unfortunatly when this line is drawn, my onClicklistener isnt called anymore. But the Button is still clickable (Color turns blue for default android button).

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener,
    OnClickListener {

// DrawView drawView;

private int number;
private Handler handler;
private boolean Running = true;
private int endX = 50;
private int endY = 500;
private int startX = 50;
private int startY = 50;
private int frames = 25;
ImageView Line01;
Button button2;
Button buttonLineDrawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // drawView = new DrawView(this);
    // drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    Line01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Line01);
    Line01.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Button buttonLineDrawer;
    buttonLineDrawer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLineDrawer);
    buttonLineDrawer.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button2;
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonLineDrawer:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "klick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Running = true;

        number = 0;
        drawLine();

        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "klick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        break;
    }

}

public void drawLine() {
    Line01.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (Running) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int coordX = ((((endX - startX) / frames) * number))
                                + startX;
                        int coordY = ((((endY - startY) / frames) * number))
                                + startY;
                        number += 1;
                        CustomDraw.setCoordinates(startX, startY, coordX,
                                coordY);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        if ((coordX - endX) == 0 && coordY - endY == 0) {
                            Running = false;

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

}

Comment: where you implemented this DrawView in your xml.

Comment: I inflate the xml in the DrawView. Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: yes they are correct, problem is, that the buttons work perfectly until the line is drawn. The toasts of both Buttons arent displayed, but the button turns typical blue when I click it.

Comment: please don't ask another question into this old thread, i'm really confused with whats actualy asked and what oyur actual progress is...  please start a new question :-$

Comment: ok, sorry, ill do that ;)

Comment: can you post the link to that following-question

Comment: Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564485/android-button-only-clickable-once-with-custom-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can sublcass the button, and do you custom draw on there?!

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CustomDraw extends Button {

    public CustomDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomDraw(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //your custom draw here
    }

}
```

you must set that button in your layout then, as well...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="de.trialar.linedrawer.MainActivity"
>

<com.example.yourpackage.CustomDraw
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
 android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: You mean get rid of the DrawView.java and put all the code in the Custom Draw?

Comment: i mean that if you subclass the button you have all the functionability of a button PLUS you add your custom drawing on top of it...  have a try and see if it fits your needs....

Comment: hey - let me know if this works, i'm interested in your results, maybe you can even share a little picture?

Comment: Hi Martin, i tried your solution and it kind of works for me. I used your method with a Imageview instead. And my line is drawn, when i click a button. Unfortunatly when this line is drawn, my onClicklistener isnt called anymore. But the Button is still clickable (Color turns blue for default android button). I`ll update  my question

Comment: if it really worked for you, you can accept my answer ^^  if you have further question feel free to ask them again in StackOverflow

Comment: i added a update to my question, maybe u see an error, i think the Problem lies at the second "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" in the DrawLine Method, but not sure.