# Button only clickable once with Custom View

Tags: java, android

i made custom Image View, where a simple line is drawn. This drawing is triggeed by a button.
When triggered the onClicklistener isnt working anymore. But on the screen the button remains clickable, the buttons changes to a blueish color when clicked (default Android button). I think the problem might be in the "drawLine()" when the "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" is called, but not sure why and how to get rid of it. Hope you can help.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener,
    OnClickListener {

private int number;
private Handler handler;
private boolean Running = true;
private int endX = 50;
private int endY = 500;
private int startX = 50;
private int startY = 50;
private int frames = 25;
ImageView Line01;
Button buttonLineDrawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Line01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Line01);
    Line01.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Button buttonLineDrawer;
    buttonLineDrawer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLineDrawer);
    buttonLineDrawer.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "klick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    Running = true;

    number = 0;
    drawLine();

}

public void drawLine() {
    Line01.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (Running) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int coordX = ((((endX - startX) / frames) * number))
                                + startX;
                        int coordY = ((((endY - startY) / frames) * number))
                                + startY;
                        number += 1;
                        CustomDraw.setCoordinates(startX, startY, coordX,
                                coordY);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        if ((coordX - endX) == 0 && coordY - endY == 0) {
                            Running = false;

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF8800"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="de.trialar.linedrawer.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLineDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


    <de.trialar.linedrawer.CustomDraw
        android:id="@+id/Line01"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp" />
</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

**CustomDraw.java**

```
public class CustomDraw extends ImageView {
Paint paint = new Paint();

private static int endX= 500;
private static int endY= 500;
private static int startX= 50;
private static int startY= 50;
static Context context;

public CustomDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
}

public CustomDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomDraw(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);
}

public static void setCoordinates(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {

    System.out.println("SetCoordinates");
    CustomDraw.endX = endX;
    CustomDraw.endY = endY;
    CustomDraw.startX = startX;
    CustomDraw.startY = startY;
}}
```

Comment: `setContentView` is replacing the original layout with a new one, including the button you have set a listener on. You are only seeing changes in the button because you have defined the coordinates as `static`, so every CustomDraw instance shares them.

At the very least, you should add the listener again after each call to `setContentView`. Anyway, you shouldn't actually need to call setContentView multiple times to begin with...

Answer (score 0):

i think i found the problem: when you start the handler.run() you set a new Layout:

```
public void run() {
    int coordX = ((((endX - startX) / frames) * number))  + startX;
    int coordY = ((((endY - startY) / frames) * number))  + startY;
    number += 1;
    CustomDraw.setCoordinates(startX, startY, coordX, coordY);

    //maybe this is wrong
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //try instead:
    CustomDraw.invalidate();

    if ((coordX - endX) == 0 && coordY - endY == 0) {
        Running = false;
    }
}
```

i don't get why you set a new layout... i guess you want to repaint the button... that's why i added a 'repaint'-line in that code-piece above

Comment: @ivagarz pointet out that you shouldn't use static declarations on the drawButton. he's VERY RIGHT. please don't do this...